# Группировка однородных членов в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, однородные-члены, подлежащее

*Первосвященники и старейшины и весь синедрион искали...*
Предложение дано без запятых. Можно ли сгруппировать первых два однородных подлежащих без постановки запятой? Или же здесь "весь синедрион" имеет присоединительное значение и должен отделяться запятой от предыдущих подлежащих?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Первосвященники и старейшины и весь синедрион искали лжесвидетельства против Иисуса.**..

Первосвященники и старейшины — это лица, имеющие определенные должности, а синедрион — учреждение, поэтому понятна такая группировка и отсутствие запятой (оба союза И являются одиночными **соединительными**).

***Старейшинами*** называли тех, кто занимал различные общественные положения в гражданском и церковном делах, были начальниками, председателями в народных собраниях.

Термин ***первосвященники*** обозначает членов Синедриона, принадлежавших к первосвященническим родам: высших членов священнической иерархии, уже отбывших эти должности, а также взрослых мужчин из наиболее выдающихся священнических семей.

***Синедрио́н*** — в Древней Иудее — высшее религиозное учреждение, а также высший судебный орган в каждом городе.